# find sum from associative array json mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I need to write a query that finds the sum of all the associative array values of given key

```
{"cpp": "15.852628", 
"reach": "12784", 
"spend": "202.66", 
"clicks": "961", 
"actions": 
    [
        {"value": "149", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply"}, 
        {"value": "154", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d"}, 
        {"value": "7", "action_type": "comment"}, 
        {"value": "3", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save"}, 
        {"value": "434", "action_type": "link_click"},
        {"value": "15", "action_type": "post"}, 
        {"value": "50", "action_type": "post_reaction"}, 
        {"value": "6", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_block"}, 
        {"value": "509", "action_type": "post_engagement"}, 
        {"value": "509", "action_type": "page_engagement"}
    ],


    "cost_per_action_type": [
   {"value": "2", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply"}, {"value": "1.315974", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d"}, 
   {"value": "4", "action_type": "comment"}, 
   {"value": "2333", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save"}, 
   {"value": "33", "action_type": "link_click"}, 
   {"value": "3", "action_type": "post"}, {"value": "4.0532", "action_type": "post_reaction"}, 
   {"value": "3", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_block"}, {"value": "0.398153", "action_type": "post_engagement"}, 
   {"value": "43", "action_type": "page_engagement"}]    
},
{"cpp": "18", 
"reach": "28", 
"spend": "202.66", 
"clicks": "961", 
"actions": 
    [
        {"value": "19", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply"}, 
        {"value": "14", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d"}, 
        {"value": "97", "action_type": "comment"}, 
        {"value": "13", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save"}, 
        {"value": "1434", "action_type": "link_click"},
        {"value": "115", "action_type": "post"}, 
        {"value": "50", "action_type": "post_reaction"}, 
        {"value": "61", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_block"}, 
        {"value": "509", "action_type": "post_engagement"}, 
        {"value": "5091", "action_type": "page_engagement"}
    ],


     "cost_per_action_type": [
   {"value": "2", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply"}, {"value": "1.315974", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d"}, 
   {"value": "4", "action_type": "comment"}, 
   {"value": "2333", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save"}, 
   {"value": "33", "action_type": "link_click"}, 
   {"value": "3", "action_type": "post"}, {"value": "4.0532", "action_type": "post_reaction"}, 
   {"value": "3", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_block"}, {"value": "0.398153", "action_type": "post_engagement"}, 
   {"value": "43", "action_type": "page_engagement"}]
    },
```

I want to find the sum of values inside `actions` array with key name `action_type= "post_reaction"`. I expect the result to be 100. Can anybody help me. I have tried a lot but ended up nowhere. Thanks in advance.

So far I have

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(
            (
                JSON_EXTRACT(ad_insights, '$[0].actions[*].action_type')
            )
        ) as spend 
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, it will help us understand the question better. Specifically are you trying to do this adding up in a MySQL query or in PHP?

Comment: SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE((JSON_EXTRACT(ad_insights, '$[0].actions[*].action_type'))) as spend
FROM TABLE .sorry this is a partial query i have no idea how to do this. ad_insighs is the column whic contain the json values pasted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i fix it. it is possible with json table

https://mysqlserverteam.com/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/

but it is supported in mysql version 8

1)`CREATE TABLE t1(json_col JSON);`

2)

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (
    '[
{"cpp": "15.852628", 
"reach": "12784", 
"spend": "202.66", 
"clicks": "961", 
"actions": 
    [
        {"value": "149", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply"}, 
        {"value": "154", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d"}, 
        {"value": "7", "action_type": "comment"}, 
        {"value": "3", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save"}, 
        {"value": "434", "action_type": "link_click"},
        {"value": "15", "action_type": "post"}, 
        {"value": "50", "action_type": "post_reaction"}, 
        {"value": "6", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_block"}, 
        {"value": "509", "action_type": "post_engagement"}, 
        {"value": "509", "action_type": "page_engagement"}
    ],


    "cost_per_action_type": [
   {"value": "2", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply"}, {"value": "1.315974", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d"}, 
   {"value": "4", "action_type": "comment"}, 
   {"value": "2333", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save"}, 
   {"value": "33", "action_type": "link_click"}, 
   {"value": "3", "action_type": "post"}, {"value": "4.0532", "action_type": "post_reaction"}, 
   {"value": "3", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_block"}, {"value": "0.398153", "action_type": "post_engagement"}, 
   {"value": "43", "action_type": "page_engagement"}]    
},
{"cpp": "18", 
"reach": "28", 
"spend": "202.66", 
"clicks": "961", 
"actions": 
    [
        {"value": "19", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply"}, 
        {"value": "14", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d"}, 
        {"value": "97", "action_type": "comment"}, 
        {"value": "13", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save"}, 
        {"value": "1434", "action_type": "link_click"},
        {"value": "115", "action_type": "post"}, 
        {"value": "50", "action_type": "post_reaction"}, 
        {"value": "61", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_block"}, 
        {"value": "509", "action_type": "post_engagement"}, 
        {"value": "5091", "action_type": "page_engagement"}
    ],


     "cost_per_action_type": [
   {"value": "2", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply"}, {"value": "1.315974", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_conversation_started_7d"}, 
   {"value": "4", "action_type": "comment"}, 
   {"value": "2333", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.post_save"}, 
   {"value": "33", "action_type": "link_click"}, 
   {"value": "3", "action_type": "post"}, {"value": "4.0532", "action_type": "post_reaction"}, 
   {"value": "3", "action_type": "onsite_conversion.messaging_block"}, {"value": "0.398153", "action_type": "post_engagement"}, 
   {"value": "43", "action_type": "page_engagement"}]
    }
    ]'
);
```

3)

```
 SELECT sum(value) 
    FROM t1, 
         JSON_TABLE(json_col, '$[*].actions[*]' COLUMNS (
                    action_type VARCHAR(180)  PATH '$.action_type',
                    value VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.value')
         ) 

post where post.action_type='post_reaction';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try and save the JSON as a normalized data first but given what you have I tried with this.

```
SELECT SUM(value) as sum_value FROM
  (SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    REPLACE(ad_insights,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_insights,'{"value": "',num),'{"value": "'),""),
    '"',1) as value,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    REPLACE(ad_insights,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_insights,'"action_type": "',num),'"action_type": "'),""),
    '"',1) as action_type
  FROM `TABLE`,
    (SELECT 1 as num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 
     UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
     UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15
     UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION SELECT 20)N
  )VAT
WHERE action_type = 'post_reaction'
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df4560/2)

-- UPDATE with content_id

```
SELECT SUM(value) as sum_value, content_id FROM
  (SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    REPLACE(ad_insights,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_insights,'{"value": "',num),'{"value": "'),""),
    '"',1) as value,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    REPLACE(ad_insights,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_insights,'"action_type": "',num),'"action_type": "'),""),
    '"',1) as action_type,
   content_id
  FROM `TABLE`,
    (SELECT 1 as num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 
     UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
     UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15
     UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION SELECT 20)N
  )VAT
WHERE action_type = 'post_reaction'
AND content_id = 200501
GROUP BY content_id
```

[sqlfiddle with content_id](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c338a5/1)

with cost per action details deleted.

```
SELECT SUM(value) as sum_value, content_id FROM
  (SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    REPLACE(ad_insights,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_insights,'{"value": "',num),'{"value": "'),""),
    '"',1) as value,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    REPLACE(ad_insights,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_insights,'"action_type": "',num),'"action_type": "'),""),
    '"',1) as action_type,
   content_id
  FROM 
   (SELECT 
      REPLACE(ad_insights,SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        REPLACE(ad_insights,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_insights,'"cost_per_action_type": [',2),'"cost_per_action_type": ['),""),
        ']',1),'DELETED 2 cost_per_action') as ad_insights
        ,content_id
        FROM
    (SELECT 
      REPLACE(ad_insights,SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        REPLACE(ad_insights,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ad_insights,'"cost_per_action_type": [',1),'"cost_per_action_type": ['),""),
        ']',1),'DELETED 1 cost_per_action') as ad_insights
        ,content_id
    FROM `TABLE`)DEL)T
    ,
    (SELECT 1 as num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 
     UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10
     UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 14 UNION SELECT 15
     UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 18 UNION SELECT 19 UNION SELECT 20)N
  )VAT
WHERE action_type = 'post_reaction'
AND content_id = 200501
GROUP BY content_id;
```

[sqlfiddle for deleted cost per action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3a6db/1)

Comment: Thank you.i have troube adding additional where clause to this query.can you please help me.`SELECT SUM(value) as sum_value,VAT.content_id FROM
  (SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
   .....
    '"',1) as action_type
  FROM conversations.conversation,
 
    (SELECT 1 as num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 
     ......)N
  )VAT
WHERE action_type = 'post_reaction'
and VAT.content_id=200501`

Comment: you have to add content_id into the inner select first then you can select it on the outer query using VAT. Because content_id probably comes from `TABLE` so you need to select it in the inner select so that it's available as a field in VAT as well.

Comment: hi ,thank you.but a small problem. i have another key called cost_per_action_type which also contain post_reaction.current query consider post_reaction inside cost_per_action_type also. i only want post_reaction inside action key. question is updated.

Comment: hi can you please help?

Comment: see bottom of answer again with new query and sqlfiddle

Comment: Highly appreciated your effort.seems like you are explicitly removing cost per actions. But that won't work in my case. I just only want post reaction inside the actions. Not from anywhere else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not removing it in database only removing it for the query so that your data comes from actions. your data is still there. If you do a query after my query none of the data is deleted, it's only deleted for that query run which doesn't affect your data at all.

Comment: I mean there are lot of object along with cost per action also come. Like cost per clicking share count etc etc..

Comment: not sure what you mean but with that query you can get post reaction only from actions and for others you can use the previous query (query #2) if you want..up to you...my queries are only guides and one way to get at the data you want feel free to change them to your needs.

Comment: if you want more logics it's probably better to pull the field back into php or whatever and deal with the JSON there.

Comment: Sir, what I mean is along with actions and cost per actions associative array there are lot of associative array will come. So I need to write big query to remove each of that. Right?like you removed cost per action. Is there any scalable solution in that case.

Comment: It'd be much easier to handle in php.

Comment: I am using php. Laravel

Comment: Not familiar with php side of things (I always have to look things up when i work with PHP) but it'd be easier in php. I am sure of it.

Comment: If it was me I'd save each value/action pair as a row in the database in a different table (normalized).

Comment: Are you comfortable with json extract in mysql?

Comment: nope nevewr used it before and it's not available on SQLfiddle mysql 5.6 so i can't play with it either